# Column nowrap using datatables not working

Tags: datatables

Having a Datatable as below:

[image: Datatable]

"Wifi Code" shows the wifi code value, and if the user has provided an email/phone, a respective button is added also to send email/Sms.

I'm trying to display "Wifi Code" in one line, with no wrap.

The table definition:

```
<table id="visitorsTable" class="display compact responsive nowrap" style="width: 100%">
```

The ColumnDefs:

```
columnDefs: [                    
            {
                targets: [10], // Wifi Code
                className: "noWrapTd", // white-space: nowrap;
                render: function(wifiCode, b, data, d) {
                    // wifi exists
                    if (wifiCode) {
                        var content = `<span class="mx-2">${wifiCode}</span>`;
                        if (data.Email && data.PhoneNumber) {
                            content +=
                                '<div>' +
                                '<button type="button" class="btnResendByMail mx-1">Email <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></button>' +
                                '<button class="btnResendBySms">Sms <i class="fas fa-sms"></i></button>' +
                                '</div>';
                            return content;
                        } else {
                            if (data.Email) {
                                content +=
                                    '<button class="btnResendByMail">Email <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></button>';
                            }
                            if (data.PhoneNumber) {
                                content +=
                                    '<button class="btnResendBySms">SMS <i class="fas fa-sms"></i></button>';
                            }
                        }
                        return content;
                    } else { // wifi does not exists
                        return '<button class="btnGenerate">Generate <i class="fas fa-wifi"></i></button>';
                    }
                }
            }
```

As you can already see, I have added the "nowrap" class to the table definition.

I've also tried to set a class "className: "noWrapTd", still not good.

Any other idea ?

Comment: By chance, have you defined somewhere within your stylesheets 'noWrapTd' class styling and is there a possibility those can be overwritten by another css, loaded **later on** and styling all possible td's?

Comment: I have defined this: `.noWrapTd {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }` as embedded style but still with no effect, even though I can see it applied with inspect element

Comment: You forgot a comma, no? `className: "noWrapTd",` Also  remove the float-right classes

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I had the comma in the app, and I also tried to remove `float-right` classes but still with no effect

Comment: Did you remove them as I said?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy yes I removed them but it did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Modified code:

```
columnDefs: [
                {
                    targets: [10], // Wifi Code
                    className: "no-wrap",
                    width: "200px",
                    render: function(wifiCode, b, data, d) {
                        // wifi exists
                        if (wifiCode) {
                            var content = "<span class="mx-2">${wifiCode}</span>";
                            if (data.Email && data.PhoneNumber) {
                                content +=
                                    '<div class="d-inline">' +
                                    '<button type="button" class="btnResendByMail d-inline mx-1">Email <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></button>' +
                                    '<button class="btnResendBySms d-inline">Sms <i class="fas fa-sms"></i></button>' +
                                    '</div>';
                                return content;
                            } else {
                                if (data.Email) {
                                    content +=
                                        '<button class="btnResendByMail d-inline">Email <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></button>';
                                }
                                if (data.PhoneNumber) {
                                    content +=
                                        '<button class="btnResendBySms d-inline">Sms <i class="fas fa-sms"></i></button>';
                                }
                            }

                            return content;
                        } else { // wifi does not exists
                            return '<button class="btnGenerate d-inline">Generate <i class="fas fa-wifi"></i></button>';
                        }
                    }
                }               
            ]
```

First of all I removed the `nowrap` class from table definition:

```
<table id="visitorsTable" class="display compact responsive" style="width: 100%">
```

And the columnDefs:

1. `className: "no-wrap"`, // Datatables no-wrap class
2. `width: "200px"`, // Fixed width
3. Applied `d-inline` class for the buttons and the div containing the buttons